# How to make a label static

Tags: c#, wpf, class, static, label

So I have a program in which I am telling the user whether two skeletons match, but the thing is that I need to access the `label` via a `class`. The error I keep getting is

```
Error1  An object reference is required for the
non-static field, method, or property 
'WpfApplication1.MainWindow.matchLabel'
```

Here's what I have in my code:

#### The `static` Label

```
static Label matching
    {
        get { return matchLabel; } //errors here
        set { matchLabel = value; } //and here
    }
```

#### The Class

```
private class Scan
    {
        private void Start()
        {
            Skeleton skeleton = new Skeleton();

            if (PersonDetected == true)
            {
                int SkeletonID2 = skeleton.TrackingId;

                if (SkeletonID1 == SkeletonID2)
                {
                    matching.Content = "Your IDs are Matching!";
                }

                else if (SkeletonID2 != SkeletonID1)
                {
                    matching.Content = "Your IDs don't Match.";
                }
            }
        }

        private void Stop()
        {
            if (PersonDetected == true)
            {
                matching.Content = "Scan Aborted";
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically I want to know how to make the label in `wpf` `static`, or if there is another way to do this. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you could use another approach, like @Daniel said, using UI elements on multiple threads is a bad idea.

If my understanding is correct, you just want to **notify** to the user the result from your domain logic, the way I would do it is simple, create an event:

`public event Action<string> MyEvent = delegate { };`

```
            if (SkeletonID1 == SkeletonID2)
            {
                this.MyEvent("Your IDs are Matching!");
            }

            else if (SkeletonID2 != SkeletonID1)
            {
                this.MyEvent("Your IDs don't Match.");
            }

 if (PersonDetected == true)
            {
                this.MyEvent("Scan Aborted");
            }
```

In your WPF view

`this.MydomainComponent.MyEvent += (x) => { this.matchLabel.Content = x; };`

Comment: Hmmmm never thought of that. Will try

Comment: What is the `MydomainComponent`?

Comment: In this case it's your `Scan` class, the class that will expose and raise the event

Comment: Ah Thats an interesting feature

Comment: I think this is a useful solution.  Can you explain what is happening on this line?

this.MydomainComponent.MyEvent += (x) => { this.matchLabel.Content = x; };

some kind of lambda function on the right, and an increment and reassign on the left.

Comment: `this.MydomainComponent.MyEvent +=` that's the syntax to add a handler for an event, `(x) => ` that's a lambda expression (a delegate shortcut) `{ this.matchLabel.Content = x; }` this is the body of the anonymous delegate function that will be called when the event is raised. `this.matchLabel.Content = x;` that's just setting the content of a label with the parameter passed from the event, in this case a string defined like `public event Action<string> MyEvent = delegate { };` You need to call the event from somewhere else to trigger everything, like this `this.MyEvent("Your IDs are ...");`

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea. You shouldn't create UI elements on multiple threads.

You really should consider implementing the MVVM pattern. It will make your code more decoupled and increase testablility.

Comment: Can you give some links and/or references

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to make labels static

Comment: @Daniel - I think it helps to provide more info to those who may not be up to speed on WPF.  Throwing out "Use MVVM" as a solution to any WPF problem is not always helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use the built in WPF Databinding.  You can use the MVVM pattern but it's not required for this to work.

Window Class (XAML)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MyWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=MyLabelValue}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window Code Behind (Code)

```
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MyWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MyWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MyWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;  // Sets context of binding to the class 
        }


        // Property for binding
        private string _mylabelvalue;
        public string MyLabelValue
        {
            get { return _mylabelvalue; }
            set 
            { 
                _mylabelvalue = value;
                if(PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyLabelValue"));
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

By using this method when you set / call the property on the window you get the value for the label.  When you change the property - you update the value in the UI via data binding and the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.  I have a section on doing this via reflection and using the MVVM pattern on my blog here.

http://tsells.wordpress.com/category/mvvm/

Comment: Hmm, will try. Thanks for your fast response that doesnt make me have to redo everything either ;)