# Values in xaml is not reflecting in the other classes in a wpf c# application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, kinect

I'm working on a wpf kinect project, its one of the developer toolkit samples of windows kinect and its called "Kinect Explorer" you can download it from the kinect developer toolkit sdk ver 1.5, in the kinectwindow.xaml i added a button and a checkbox, also there is a class called kinectskeleton.cs in which i created two datatables and a boolean variables, the first datatable is filled in the onrender function while the other is empty and the boolean variable is set by default to false.
so what i want is when the button in the kinectwindow.xaml.cs is pressed the latest data in the filled datatable is copied to the empty one, then when the checkbox is checked the boolean value is set to true, so how to do this?

i defined a function in the class kinectskeleton.cs that copies the data from the filled to the empty datable, and in the onclick function of the button of kinectwindow.xaml.cs i created an opbject from class kinectskeletion and called this function but both datatables are empty, same for the checkbox in the checkbox_checked function i set the boolean value of the class kinectskelton to true and in the unchecked function i set it to false, but the result that in the kinectskelton class its always set to the default value false never enters the if condition i made to enter when its true.

Hope its now more clear and waiting for any suggestions.
to download the toolkit here is the link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/developer-downloads.aspx

Comment: Please provide some code. What you are writing is not very clear.

Comment: please add some punctuation and line breaks, your text is horrible to read :(

Comment: Agreed. This is not very clear.  Are you using code behind, MVVM? etc. There is not enough info to go on to offer any help

Comment: You really should include some code so that it'll possible to help you without downloading the SDK and trying to modify the example by following your instructions.

Comment: i posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462782/access-the-value-of-button-and-checkbox-of-an-xaml-in-other-another-class-in-a-w

Answer (score -1):

Do you call any equivalent to OnPropertyChanged("yourProperty")  ?

Your GUI needs to somehow get the information that the variable has changed.

Comment: Tomas. That is assuming that we have bound values. It is not clear from the question if this is the case.

Comment: @user1460166 The question is still not clear, and does not have any code

Comment: i posted another question with code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462782/access-the-value-of-button-and-checkbox-of-an-xaml-in-other-another-class-in-a-w   can you please check it