# making button .xaml public to another class in wpf controller

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf-controls

I have this button from  Main window.xaml need to call it from another class
i made it just like first answer
    [How to make a control in XAML public in order to be seen in other classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425153/how-to-make-a-control-in-xaml-public-in-order-to-be-seen-in-other-classes)

```
 <Window x:Class="USD.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="525"> 

<Button  ToolTip="Answer Call" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="107,82,0,0"  x:Name="answerCall"  Click="answerCall_Click"  Visibility="Hidden" x:FieldModifier="public">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Image  Width="35" Height="35" Source="Images/unnamed.png" RenderTransformOrigin="4.075,0.607">
            </Image>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

but when i checked it from any .cs class just like that

```
MainWindow.answerCall.Visibility.Visible;
```

give errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it by this in C# code

```
 DispatcherPriority.Background,
                    new Action(() => ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow).answerCall.Visibility = Visibility.Visible));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use a controller/viewmodel, you shouldn't have any code behind, instead of that, you should work with [bindable properties](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/04/20/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-two.html) and [commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx), implementing [INotifyPropertyChanged interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx), in some base class if you want.

Comment: i do not use controller/viewmodel , just simple button i want make it visable if there is value in class.cs

Comment: Ok, I told you that because you wrote "WPF Controller" in the title.